# I am not able to custom style my password fields in registration form in django

Tags: django, web, backend

I am trying to add bootstrap on my User registration form and the problem I am getting is that All the fields are styled except the password and password confirmation fields. Here is my code:

My forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class mysignupform(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True,widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','first_name','last_name','email','password1','password2']
        widgets= {

            'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'first_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'last_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'password1':forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'password2':forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),

        }
        def save(self,commit=True):
            user = super(mysignupform,self).save(commit=False)
            user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user
```

Comment: Is it showing like custom html password input without any css?

Comment: Yeah, the password and password confirmation fields are showing like custom html password input with no bootstrap effects! Only the email, first_name, last_name, and username fields appear with bootstrap effects........